# Once a contact is selected from address book, how do I extract vCard and send it? All I want to do is to replicate 'Send to User' functionality

Tags: android

```
 public void sendSms(View v)
 {

     EditText n1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
        EditText n2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);
        //EditText msg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sms);

        //Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
     String phone_Num1= n1.getText().toString();
     String phone_Num2= n2.getText().toString();
    // String send_msg=msg.getText().toString();
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phone_Num1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     //SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
      getVcardString();
    /* PendingIntent piSent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
     PendingIntent piDelivered=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
     sms.sendTextMessage( phone_Num1,null,"Contact this number "+phone_Num2.toString(),  piSent, piDelivered);
     sms.sendTextMessage( phone_Num2,null,"Contact this number "+phone_Num1.toString(),  piSent, piDelivered);*/

 }
```

I used this code to exchange contact between two people using string format.
But i want to exchange vcard through message.plz help me.or send some code in detail

this is the code which i'm using to select contact from saved list
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

```
int n=0;
int n1=0;
// Check which request it is that we're responding to
if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {

    // Make sure the request was successful
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Get the URI that points to the selected conta
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        // We only need the NUMBER column, because there will be only one row in the result
        String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};

        // Perform the query on the contact to get the NUMBER column
        // We don't need a selection or sort order (there's only one result for the given URI)
        // CAUTION: The query() method should be called from a separate thread to avoid blocking
        // your app's UI thread. (For simplicity of the sample, this code doesn't do that.)
        // Consider using CursorLoader to perform the query.
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
        int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
        String number = cursor.getString(column);
        n++;
        number = number.replace("-" ,"");
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        EditText no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
        if(!no.equals(" "))
        {
            String no_t = number+no.getText();
            no.setText(no_t);
        }

         //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++)
        {

       num[i]=number;   
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), num[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        // Do something with the phone number...


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the first step is to get the vCard file itself. 
You can do that by using a cursor to grab the path to the file:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY};
Cursor contacts =  contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, null,  null, null);
if(contacts.moveToFirst()){
    do{
           String path = contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
           Uri vcardPath = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, path);
      } while (contacts.moveToNext());
}
```

So now you have the path to vCard stored in vcardPath for each contact.

To share it, you just need to fire off an intent with it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/vcard");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, vcardPath);
ShareActionProvider provider = new ShareActionProvider(context);
provider.setShareIntent(intent);
```

If you want to create the vcf file yourself, you can use this code:

```
File vcfFile = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "generated.vcf");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(vcfFile);
fw.write("BEGIN:VCARD\r\n");
fw.write("VERSION:3.0\r\n");
fw.write("N:" + lastName + ";" + firstName + "\r\n");
fw.write("FN:" + firstName + " " + lastName + "\r\n");
fw.write("ORG:" + companyName + "\r\n");
fw.write("TITLE:" + title + "\r\n");
fw.write("TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:" + workPhone + "\r\n");
fw.write("TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:" + homePhone + "\r\n");
fw.write("ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;" + street + ";" + city + ";" + state + ";" + postalCode + ";" + country + "\r\n");
fw.write("EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:" + emailAddress + "\r\n");
fw.write("END:VCARD\r\n");
fw.close();
```

Refer to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard to see format options

---

Updated answer:

```
if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        // We only need the NUMBER column, because there will be only one row in the result
        String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
            .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);

        //Grab the vCard path
        int lookupKey = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY);
        Uri vcardPath = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI,     cursor.getString(lookupKey));

        String number = cursor.getString(column);
        n++;
        number = number.replace("-" ,"");
        EditText no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
        if(!no.equals(" "))
        {
            String no_t = number+no.getText();
            no.setText(no_t);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++)
        {
           num[i]=number;   
        }
    }
}
```

Store the vcardPath somewhere and when you want to share the file you use the intent that I have written above

Comment: Weather i have to write first part of code in seperate function??

Comment: Depends, that just loops through all contacts on the phone and grabs the path to the vCard. How are you generating your address book?

Comment: Actually first i'm created some contact and saved it.After that i'm selecting contact from that list.So now i want to convert that selected contact to .vcf file.How to do it?

Comment: Please post your code that creates and saves the contact

Comment: You can either create the vcf manually (see my edit for that), or if you were able to store the id of the contact you created on the phone, you could query the cursor for the contact and grab the path to the vcf file.

Comment: can i add that converting part code in onActivityResult function? or i have to create seperate function for that or i can do it in try catch statement?

Comment: No. I can help you, but I can't do the entire thing for you. Let me know how I can assist you further

Comment: the code which you sent me is not working in the sence converting part is not working